# How can i read local file from D drive in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-analytics

My requirement is to read the json file which contains some data and store in some other .js file.

I got task to read local file from local disk in Javascript , i have used file path like - D:\json\analytics.json.

```
(document).ready(){
($).getData("D:\json\analytics.json");

}
```

when i see in firebug it takes other url.

How I can do it, is it possible to read file from javascript.

I don't know javascript , i have seen some answer but i am not able to understand .

Need Solution , how I can achieve it. is there any other way to read file on jsp without using scriptlet . From server side , can send it on the jsp page.

Comment: use the file protocol - `file:///D:/json/analytics.json`

Comment: are you reading it from server path or user machine?

Comment: now i am trying to read from user machine

Comment: @JaromandaX i have search , can not read file from local machine in Javascript, because of security reason, javascript does not supports

Comment: yes, I know there's restrictions when reading from local drive, but you didn't ask about that, I merely pointed out the correct syntax for file protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Jaronmanda's answer won't work cause it will hit cross origin issue, see ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local]).

As the page suggested, in general you need to serve that json file from a web service (same domain, or allow your domain to access), but it depends on what you really need to do. If you can control where that json file is stored, the easier way is to put that in a subdirectory of your html file, and do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $.get('<directory>/analytics.json', function (data) {
        // Do your stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: `I think Jaronmanda's answer won't work cause it will hit cross origin issue` - I never posted an answer, I merely informed the OP of the correct syntax for file protocol. If the page is loaded using file:///, the there is a small chance he could read that file ... but that was not part of the question anyway

Comment: @Natural Lam Thanks for your answer , I have done same way.  Thanks for your answer,  it was my first experience with javascript , after solving this , i got experience with javascript , :)